# How to fix an error when an empty string is being written to elastic search from an Apache Spark job?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, elasticsearch-hadoop

There is an exception being thrown when I execute my Scala app with functionality of `myRDD.saveToEs` (I also tried saveToEs from a dataframe). My ES version is `2.3.5`.
I am using Spark `1.5.0` so maybe there is a way to configure this in the `SparkContext` which I am not aware of.

The stack trace is as under -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Found unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse [foo_eff_dt];Invalid format: ""; Bailing out..
at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The field named `foo_eff_dt` does have values and in certain cases doesnt (i.e., *empty*). I am not sure if this is causing the exception.

My scala code snippet looks like this :

```
fooRDD.saveToEs("foo/bar")
```

Please help/guide me in resolving this.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to insert Date into Elastic and in Elastic Date can be empty.

```
{
"format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
"type": "date"
 }
```

If you don't have strict need for date field then you can easily resolve this by changing this into string.